# How to adjust date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, datetime

Right now, I have the data for ORGDate but not in the format I need it in.

I tried select convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,ORGDate)) but it outputs as

| What I have | What I need | What my Query gives me |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10291 | 10/02/91 | 03/06/1928 |
| 63098 | 06/30/98 | 10/03/2072 |
| 22282 | 02/22/82 | 01/03/1961 |

I tried select convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,ORGDate)) but the output is not what I am looking for

Comment: What happened if you add leading zero, where the first 2 digits are lower than 13, then convert it to date with pattern: `dd/MM/yy`?

Comment: What database provider?

Comment: `11199` would be `11/01/99` or `01/11/99`?

Comment: How do you know if it's the day or the month that is represented by 2 digits if it can vary? Curiously what is the intention behind casting to an imprecise float-point numeric format?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel, good point! Another option is: `11/11/99`, because... how to know which part of 11 have to be converted into month or day. :)

Comment: @AndersonPimentel that is an excellent point, that I didn't even consider and unfortunately can't answer so this might be a data quality issue that we will have to fix internally

Comment: @MaciejLos Would I be able to add in the leading zeros myself? or does the data need to be cleaned to include those leading zeros?

Comment: There's much more to do... See: https://dbfiddle.uk/YEDPS0Zr

Answer (score 0):

Try with *DateFromParts*:

```sql
Select DateFromParts(ORGDate % 100 + 1900, ORGDate / 10000, ORGDate / 100 % 100) As TrueDate
```